# MS SQL 2008 R2 64bit will not use more than 1.5GB in task manager

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008

I have the latest MS SQL 2008 R2 installed on Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit.  The SQL server process never surpasses 1.5GB in the task manager resulting in heavy disk usage.  I have solve this problem before in a 2003/SQL 2005 32bit environment by enabling PAE and AWE.  I was under the impression that switching to 64-bit for everything will solve the 4GB memory limit.

Comment: Does your server actually have more than 2GB of RAM installed and available?

Comment: Do you have any memory restictions configured on the SQL instance? Under "Properties" -> "Memory".  I can confirm 64 bit SQL doesn't have trouble using avaiable RAM, here's a [screenshot of two instances](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Swmx.png), one using ~48GB and one ~11GB.  Also, have you been actively using this instance? Most RAM usage seems to come from query caching, and will be flushed at restart.

Comment: Yes 16GB is installed.  The memory values is set as default with 0 min and 2147483647 max.  How can I confirm that I am running the 64bit version of SQL2008 R2, since I wasn't the one to install that part?

Comment: @TienTran: SELECT @@VERSION returns: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4266.0 (X64) <-- note the x64

Comment: Yes confirmed. Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64) Jun 11 2012 16:41:53 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @TienTran: try setting the minimum to 2 GB to see if that takes effect.

Comment: I just noticed that its the Express version.  Isn't that limited to 1GB ram?  I'll install the full version to check.  So sorry.

Comment: @TienTran Ah, Express, yes, you're going to be limited. Please post that as an answer and mark it "accepted" when you are able.